# Command to remove a portion of JSON data from each line?

Tags: text-processing, string, json

I have `test.json` file with different lengths of rows. Some fictitious example:

```
{ a: 123, b: sd, c: x45, d: 1, e: '' }
{ a: 5, b: bfgg, c: x4c, d: 31, e: '' }
```

I want to cut the whole substring after `d` - part and get back just for every line:

```
{ a: 123, b: sd, c: x45 }
{ a: 5, b: bfgg, c: x4c }
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397698/how-to-cut-a-string-after-a-specific-character-in-unix) a similar question and tried to adapt my problem to it:

```
echo test.json |  sed 's/. d:/' > newtest.json
```

I need to do it for the whole file, not only one line.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not JSON (need [double] quotes around any strings) </pedantic>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed '/d:/s/, d:[^}]*/ /' test.json
```

it will walk through the whole file and remove on each line with `d:` all `, d:.*` part till `}` symbol (`}` symbol will stay on the line).

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing much with transforming json on the command line, it is well worth your time to get the jq tool and learn to use it.

http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

While the answers above show that you can do minimal transformations without actually parsing the json, eventually you will either reinvent a buggy json parser via regexp or revert to using the native json parser in your language of choice.

jq is fast, simple to use and a very handy tool to have in your toolbox.

BWT, your test data is invalid json, which will complicate the solutions above. 
If you fix it to

```
{ "a":123 , "b": "sd", "c": "x45", "d": 1, "e": "" }
{ "a":5 , "b": "bfgg", "c": "x4c", "d": 31, "e": "" }
```

Then this jq command will do want you want

```
 jq -c '{a,b,c}' test.json

{"a":123,"b":"sd","c":"x45"}
{"a":5,"b":"bfgg","c":"x4c"}
```

Comment: thanks, this is cool. Sorry, my json is valid, I just create some example without strings "" (in the real file all keys and values in the dictionary are strings)

Answer (score 4):

@Rush's answer using `sed` is likely the best way to solve this but here's how you can do it using `awk` too:

```
$ awk -F ', d.* ' '{print $1, $2}' file.txt 
{ a: 123, b: sd, c: x45 }
{ a: 5, b: bfgg, c: x4c }
```

The above uses `awk` to split the data on `, d.*`. This produces 2 fields of data, `$1` and `$2` which contain the data resulting from AWK's splitting of the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Through Perl which uses Positive lookahead assertion,

```
$ perl -pe 's/,\s+d:\s+.*?(?= })//' file
{ a: 123, b: sd, c: x45 }
{ a: 5, b: bfgg, c: x4c }
```

Through Python,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import re
file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = re.sub(r',\s+d:\s+.*?(?= })', r'', line)
        print(line, end='')
```

Paste the above code in a file `script.py` and run the srcipt on your terminal by,

```
python3 script.py /path/to/the/input/file
```

Output:

```
{ a: 123, b: sd, c: x45 }
{ a: 5, b: bfgg, c: x4c }
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't use Perl, but do a lot of code in Python. Actually I have interested on specific solution in Linux (like awk, sed or probably grep), because I want collect some experience in this area. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a valid JSON file containing a set of objects, like

```json
{"a":123,"b":"sd","c":"x45","d":1,"e":"''"}
{"a":5,"b":"bfgg","c":"x4c","d":31,"e":"''"}
```

or the equivalent

```json
{
  "a": 123,
  "b": "sd",
  "c": "x45",
  "d": 1,
  "e": "''"
}
{
  "a": 5,
  "b": "bfgg",
  "c": "x4c",
  "d": 31,
  "e": "''"
}
```

and you'd like to remove the `d` and `e` keys from each object.

Using `jq`, deleting one key at a time:

```bash
jq -c 'del(.d) | del(.e)' file.json
```

Deleting both keys at once:

```bash
jq -c 'del(.d, .e)' file.json
```

The result of either of these would be

```json
{"a":123,"b":"sd","c":"x45"}
{"a":5,"b":"bfgg","c":"x4c"}
```

A third way of doing this, which doesn't mention the actual keys by name, would be to convert the objects to lists of "entries" using `to_entries`, then delete the last two entries and convert the list back to a modified object:

```bash
jq -c 'to_entries | del(.[-2:]) | from_entries' file.json
```

This is most like what the text of the question proposes and the result depends on the ordering of the keys in the object.